# MySQL select top ten records with no duplicate uid

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following table (user_record) with millions of rows like this:

```
no    uid   s
================
1       a   999
2       b    899
3       c   1234
4       a    1322
5       b    933
-----------------
```

The uid can be duplicate .What I need is to show the top ten records(need inclued uid and s) with no  duplicate uid order by s (desc). I can do this by two steps in the following SQL statements:

```
SELECT distinct(uid) FROM user_record ORDER BY s DESC LIMIT 10
SELECT uid,s FROM user_record WHERE uid IN(Just Results)
```

I just wana know is there a bit more efficient way in one statement?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

ps:I also have following the SQL statement:

```
 select * from(select uid,s from user_record order by s desc) as tb group by tb.uid order by tb.s desc limit 10
```

but it's slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpliest would be by using `MAX()` to get the highest `s` for every `uid` and sorted it based on the highest `s`.

```
SELECT  uid, MAX(s) max_s
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY uid
ORDER   BY max_s DESC
LIMIT   10
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3be43/1)

The disadvantage of the query above is that it doesn't handles duplicates if for instance there are multiple `uid` that have the same `s` and turn out to be the highest value. If you want to get the highest value `s` with duplicate, you can do by calculating it on the subquery and joining the result on the original table.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT s
            FROM    TableName
            ORDER   BY s DESC
            LIMIT 10
        ) b ON a.s = b.s
ORDER   BY s DESC
```